# Form elements do not have associated labels, but it is a MUI theme switch

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, accessibility, lighthouse

I have a theme switch (light to dark) on my page, using Material UI switch. I get an error from lighthouse stating that it needs a label, but if I make a text label it will impact the design and make it worse. Are there any solutions to this?
[image]

Also, here is the error from Lighthouse

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an [`aria-label`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/Attributes/aria-label) to the `Switch`:

```
<Switch
  checked = {checked}
  onChange = {handleChange}
  inputProps = {{ 'aria-label': 'theme' }}
/>
```

You may use other attributes in `inputProps` as well (e.g. `aria-labelledby`, `title`).

One of the categories Lighthouse checks for is Accessibility. When certain elements like your `Switch` do not have an accessible name, an `aria-label` may be used to provide the element with an accessible name.